# React application forces user to log in every time after closing browser (react-oidc-context)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

Was wondering if someone have an example that shows how to set up so that the application automatically lets user in if the user has logged in earlier and have a valid token with react-oidc-context.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Isn't https://github.com/authts/react-oidc-context what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

react-oidc-context uses session storage by default to store the token, and the session storage got cleared when you close the tab/browser.

To fix it you need to use the local storage instead by adding this to the settings:

```
const oidcConfig = {
  userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({
    store: localStorage
  }),
```